# Woocommerce how to change the sidebars of cart,checkout,my account pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I trying to integrate woo commerce shopping cart with my existing WordPress site.For that I created a new woocommerce.php file in the theme folder( In which i am calling woocommerce_content()).I also registered two new sidebarsI(say left-sidebar and right-sidebar).I am using these two new sidebars in the woocommerce.php page to display product categories,product filter etc..Product page is working fine.
But my cart,checkout,account pages are not working as per the design.I think it is using the page.php template therefore it is not displaying the new sidebars.Please help me to change this sidebars.
I need to display the new sidebars in the following pages

1,Products page
2,Cart page
3,Checkout page
4,Account page

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you edit your post with the contents of your `woocommerce.php` file?

Comment: in woocommerce.php I edited the page.php file and replaced the loop with woocommerce_content()

Comment: Is there any chance that your Cart, Checkout and Account pages are using some other page template, one that's overriding `woocommerce.php`?

Comment: Buddy,
By default the Cart,Checkout,Account pages will use page.php.

Comment: I'm well aware. I just wondered if you'd happened to override that default with your own page template — say `no-sidebar.php` or something of that nature. That could explain your issue.

Comment: And you can't do is_woocommerce() on the checkout page so how do you put in a conditional to for example not show something on the WooCommerce checkout page that you have on other WP pages?